# Filter out categories that have no items

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve the hierarchy of all categories that have products.

Here is my table structure:
[image]

And the category structure will be:

```
Categ A
      ^--Categ B
               ^--Categ C
                        ^-- Prod 1
                        ^-- Prod 2
               ^--Categ D
      ^--Categ E
               ^--Categ F
               ^--Categ G
```

For the structure shown above I want to filter out **Categ D, Categ E ,Categ F, Categ G** because they don't have any products **or** any subcategories that have products.

Comment: please show some sample data as well.

Comment: I don't think the sample data is needed for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this iteratively.  Just run this delete until no records are returned:

```
delete c
    from category c left join
         category child
         on c.id = child.parent_id
    where child.id is null and
          not exists (select 1 from category_productd cp where cp.categ_id = c.id) ;
```

You have a hierarchical data structure.  MySQL really provides no support for such structures beyond looping.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I've edited the last line. I want to filter out not remove them form the database.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just fetch all categories with a product instead of removing categories without one? The first Thing can be done by an inner-join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM category_product as a
JOIN product as b
ON a.prod_id = b.id
```

Comment: If I do your way I will get only the categories that have products, but I want the hierarchical structure for categories.